# php regex negative lookahead find anywhere

Tags: php, regex, pcre

In a php file I want to find all lines that echo out something, but where the echo does not contain any HTML. The purpose of this is to do a search replace to implement XSS protection.

My test string looks like this:

```
<?php foreach($this->userlist as $u) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo '<h1>'.$u['user_id'];?>" <?php echo $this->wfe->job['created_by']==$u['user_id']?'selected':'';?>><?php echo $u['real_name'];?></option>
<?php }; ?>
```

My regular "base" expression is:

```
<\?php\secho\s(.*?)\?>
```

I have then tried to insert various **negative lookahead** expressions inside my match No1:

```
(?!('<)) - excludes my '<h1>' tag echo successfully

(?!(\$)) - excludes my other echo statements
```

However

```
(?!^.*<[^>]+.*) - does not exclude any of my echo statements
(?!.*<[^>]+.*) - excludes all of my echo statements
```

How can I only exclude my echo statement including ?

I have recorded the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/hDufvl/2

Comment: "search replace to implement XSS protection" I can pretty much guarantee that any search-and-replace solution to XSS attacks won't be complete.

Comment: @Chris thanks but it will reduce the risk. This will be combined with manual review as well, once automatic search/ replace has been done

Answer (score 0):

```
/<\?php\s+echo\b(?:.(?!<[a-z]))*?\?>/gsi
```

https://regex101.com/r/hDufvl/5

I think this may give you a false sense of your coverage. Nothing replaces proper review.

Comment: I have actually since found a better way to handle XSS, but keen to learn what I did wrong